# document based app is not appearing in 'open with' option in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

There is a document reader app which is designed to open a specific extension file from other apps such as mails, dropbox. The app appears in the 'open with' option till iOS 12. But the same when tried in iOS 13 beta, the app is not listing in the options shown in 'open with'.

Kindly let me know, is there any particular change required to be done for iOS 13 info.plist to make the app appear in the list? 
All the recommended settings such as CFBundleDocumentTypes,LSItemContentTypes and Exported Type UTI as suggested by Apple for opening document based app from other apps have been done. The issue still exists in iOS 13 only.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same issue when updating my app to iOS 13 environment. I did some research and found this post works for me: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/383499#383279

I changed value to the `UTTypeConformsTo` key from "application/prs.xxxxdata" (some arbitrary name) to "public.data" and my app returned to the "Open With" list when trying to open the specific filetype.

Comment: Yes @tttemplar. This works. Thanks a lot, for the reply!

Comment: This makes it return to the "open with" list of *all* file types. It just ignores the extension. What is the point of defining a custom UTI if you're going to do that?